# Book with uncontrolled/subconscious teleportation across worlds

Tags: story-identification, books, hard-sci-fi

I read this book maybe 10 years ago. I read it in German; I don't think it was a native German book though, but rather a translation.

There was a protagonist whom we followed across this book. The main thing was that there were teleporter disks, which would bring you to other places/worlds. But, you could not consciously choose where to go, instead the disks would decide where you would go, that is "what you truly and subconsciously need most right now" if I remember correctly. Which leads the protagonist to a long pilgrimage across a lot of worlds.

One of them was a planet where the inhabitants fought an eternal war; the two civilisations were divided by the equator (or did the border move throughout the battles?), and both halves were fighting each other since many many years. 
I think the inhabitants' technology level was not too high, I think it was more like a bit tribal, and they were like murlocs (those amphibian tadpole-like things from the Blizzard/Warcraft universe, and not Morlocks, from The Time Machine) or something. No one could remember the reason for the war and they did not care, or it was entirely insignificant.

Also, the worlds had different technology levels. For example, he/she finds several aircraft/spaceships, some more advanced, some less. Many had like a dark black fog/nothingness in it instead of a seat with belts, which would fixate you, but one ship had this darkness only as a seat, the other as the whole cockpit/ship.

There was another planet, where war was also going on, and he joined the fight and rode an aircraft-bike thing.

There might have been a chapter on some kind of a military base which he/she explored. Could be that I mix that up with another book.

I don't remember the gender of the protagonist, or time, or if starting place was Earth.

I initially thought it could have been a Lukianenko, because I read a lot of them at that time, but I could not find a matching book there.

Comment: Hello there, fellow Lukianenko reader! :) That's good info already, but hey, might be worth to take a look at [this guide for story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories to [edit] in. For instance, any recollection what the cover looked like? Did you read that in English, was it a translation?

Comment: While there is no match in the details, there's a similar theme (subconscious teleportation) underlying ***Finity***, by John Barnes.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the linked guide, I'll see if I can add anything with that. I have no idea about the cover, and I read it in German. I don't think it was a native German book though, but a translation.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, looks interesting, but definitely wasn't the book I am looking for. Don't think it was about alternative universes but just other worlds, also nothing about Hitler/USSR.

Comment: No, I didn't think it was going to be that book, but I thought that if you were looking for a book with a certain theme, you might find other books with similar themes interesting, and it was the first one I thought of when I saw the title, even before I read the text. If I knew of a match, I'd propose it as an actual answer, not a comment.  Sorry... :)

Comment: I guessed so, I was just trying to clarify anyway. I am thankful you did, and I am indeed currently trying to find any more hints by searching similar stories to Finity. Also, I think I will read just read it because it sounds interesing. So your comment is of double value for me ;)